# Cannot see chat room transcript while another user can

Tags: support, chat, chat-transcript

There is a chat room which was inactive for quite long: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47379/discussion-on-answer-by-euri-pinhollow-why-dont-cameras-offer-more-than-3-colou

This page says "Page not found" to me while [another user sees history with timestamps](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34279458#34279458).

Comment: Have you looked at ownership of the room, perhaps? It works for me, but then I'm a mod, so that doesn't really pin down the problem

Comment: @RoryAlsop: I cannot look at anything, it is "Page not found" for me. This was a room for me and someone else who started it automatically from comments.

Comment: Page not found for me too, I think right now only mods or users which have over 10k rep can see that room.

Comment: Seems reasonable - mods, room owners and 10k-ers

Comment: @RoryAlsop: and why not me, a participant of that room? Why does room becomes private after it expires?

Comment: @EuriPinhollow [here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhirL.png).

Comment: @EuriPinhollow it's the same as with questions and answers. When deleted, only those who wrote it can see it, plus users with proper privileges. Taking part in chat does not mean you "own" the chat room, only if you are assigned as a room owner.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I know that. Explaining the case from the system viewpoint does not make me (and other people who would want to see discussions which are linked from comments) happier.

Comment: Well, that's just how things work. You can start a feature request asking to let users who posted in a chat room see their own messages even if the room is deleted. (if you do, please start new question.)

Answer (score 5):

The room has been deleted, so only moderators and users with at least 10k network reputation can see it.  (The user who reported being able to see it has 71k rep.)

Rooms are frozen when they become inactive, and [some frozen rooms are automatically deleted](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).  Your room had only a few messages and the system deemed it not worth keeping (there are a *lot* of rooms like that that people don't end up caring about).  If you want access, I suggest you ask a moderator on that site if it can be undeleted long enough for you to copy what you need from it.

Comment: Second link is a link to user saying that he is fine with first link.

Comment: Why make rooms private? I mean, sure, they can be unlisted but why make them unreadable even for participants?

Comment: It is not reasonable to say that a room is deleted if mods can see the transcript. Really, I do not care about room itself, I need the trancsript which becomes kinda private/hidden for no reason.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow see my edit.  The system automatically deletes frozen rooms with very few messages.  "Deleted" on SE means deleted for all practical purposes; moderators need to be able to see deleted content to do their jobs.

Comment: But if it will be undeleted, won't the system auto delete it again? (same way it's freezing rooms again day after they're unfrozen.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio: I still cannot see a reason for hiding something if it is stored anyways.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I was thinking of undeleting long enough for the OP to copy the contents, not persisting forever.  Or, if people start using it again, then it wouldn't be re-deleted.  But you're right; I wasn't explicit about that.

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that this answer was referenced in my recent question: [Can room owners see their deleted rooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300213)

Comment: @Martin thanks for letting me know.  I've corrected this post.

Comment: Still, I assume that room which are frozen (but not deleted) can be seen by the owner, even if they are below 10k. (At least the experiment I mention in my question suggests that much.)

Comment: Frozen rooms are still visible to everybody who could see them before they were frozen.  The room linked in the question was deleted in November 2016.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!