# Can room owners see their deleted rooms?

Tags: support, chat, room-owner, deleted-room

Basically I just want to ask whether a room owner can see deleted room, transcript, messages in that room.

This came up in a recent conversation in chat with another user who mentioned that they [cannot see the room I linked to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39637637#39637637). I have tested and I saw that when I'm not logged in, I do not see the room either. So I thought that this is privilege tied somehow with the reputation. (Still, they were [able to see a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39637951#39637951) which was frozen rather than deleted.)

I searched a bit and found [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288603/cannot-see-chat-room-transcript-while-another-user-can/288606#288606) which says that a deleted room should be visible to "moderators, room owners, and users with at least 10k network reputation". But when I look at the [room info](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/62065/mathematical-logic), the user in question is listed there as the only room owner.

So now I am not really sure whether the information provided in the linked answer is exactly correct. (Still I have decided to tag this [support](/questions/tagged/support) rather than [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), since it is quite probable that there are some other rules about this I am unaware of.)

Comment: There is a  deleted/frozen rooms button if you click the button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTE7c.png you see frozen and deleted rooms but in incognito mode I only see frozen rooms and I can see my own frozen/delete rooms from my chat profile but I have 10K everywhere ....

Answer (score 4):

No, room ownership does not allow one to see the room after it was deleted.

Source: I am an owner of [this deleted room](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1055/log-of-meta-posts) and I get only an error message trying to access it.

Comment: I can see that room though, I'm also an RO there, I even entered it. Rep matters ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVIjb.png

Comment: @rene of course, only rep. 10k most likely, same as seeing deleted posts.

Answer (score 3):

Only users having >= 10k reputation and moderators can see the deleted rooms.

I recommend to visit 
[Is there a list of SE chat privileges, and the minimum reputation required for those privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87761/260388)

> **10k rep**:
>
> 1. be notified of spam/offensive flags (the number of active flags appears in a circle on your gravatar)
> 2. **view frozen and deleted rooms** (read access only if allowed).

- Room owners aren't privileged to list deleted rooms.
- Modetators can see deleted rooms and delete/undelete rooms.

Note that [Chat related privileges are not site specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271471/260388).

Comment: Hm... the user in question explicitly said that they see the room which was frozen (but not deleted). The same is mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288603/cannot-see-chat-room-transcript-while-another-user-can/288606#comment975706_288606). And rene mentions frozen rooms [in the comment about test in incognito mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300213/can-room-owners-see-their-deleted-rooms/300245#comment975579_300213).

Comment: Still, even if some information there contradict experiments we can all do, +1 for a useful link. (I assume the information there will be eventually corrected.)